# What to put in the options to get user by id with axios and useeffect when the endpoint in the backend doesn't have params?

Tags: reactjs, axios, parameters, get

I hope my question in the title is understandable. I also have looked up for solution since days ago, but could not find anything that works. Maybe I don't understand I don't know. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

I have successfully retrieved a user by id from MongoDB on the backend, with no params on the endpoint. Tested on Postman by writing an example id on the body. Previously, I have only retrieved user by params and never put id on the body.

This is the endpoint (I asked my mentor, he said because it is NoSQL we don't need params).

```
router.get('/getUser', getSingle)
```

And with this code on the service:

```
export const getSingleUser = async (id: string) => {
const userList = await getCollection('users')
const userData = await userList?.findOne({
    _id: new ObjectId(id)
})

console.log('user', userData)

return userData
}
```

Now I want to connect the frontend. I have tried to getAllUsers and it worked with these codes.

```
export const getAllUsers = async (): Promise<IResponse | IErrorResponse> => {
const axiosClient = AxiosClient.createInstance();

try {
    const response = await axiosClient.get("/api/v1/getAll");

    return {
        success: true,
        data: response.data
    };
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);

    return {
        success: false,
        data: isAxiosError(err) ? err.message : (err as string)
    };
}
};
```

ReactJS part

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<userData[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
    // open browser console to see result
    const getUsers = async () => {
        const response = await getAllUsers();
        // const result = response.json();
        if (response.success) {
            setUsers(response.data as userData[]);
            console.log(response.data);
        } else {
            throw Error("Cannot fetch"); // temporary
            // create error notification wth Chakra
        }
    };
    getUsers()
}, []);
```

But I really cannot find a way to retrieve a single user using id. **I don't know what to put on the options after the endpoint to define an id to search?** have tried string, the id from inside object interface and they didn't work. This is the latest trial.

```
export const getSingleUser = async(**id: string**): Promise<IResponse | IErrorResponse> =>{
const axiosClient = AxiosClient.createInstance();

try {
const response = await axiosClient.get("api/v1/getUser/", **{params: {ID: id}}**);

    return {
        success: true,
        data: response.data
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);

    return {
        success: false,
        data: isAxiosError(err) ? err.message: (err as string)
    }
}
}
```

**Also what parameter I can put in here?** I was frustrated I just put one of the ids from the database. Didnt work. Nothing happened. Console is empty.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // open browser console to see result
    const getUser = async (**id: string**) => {        
    const response = await getSingleUser(**'64e738b63ef7a62f2d9a3d60'**);

            if (response.success) {
            setSingleUser(response.data as userData[]);
            console.log(response.data);
        } else {
            throw Error("Cannot fetch"); // temporary
            // create error notification wth Chakra
        }
}
getUser(**id**)
}, []);
```

So what can I put in the options after the endpoint on the axios get function and in the parameter in the useeffect? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In your backend you can read the id from the request path:

```
router.get('/getUser/:id', getSingle)
```

And in your controller `getSingle` you can access the user id from the request path:

```
req.params.id
```

In your frontend change the request path to:

```js
export const getSingleUser = async(**id: string**): Promise<IResponse | IErrorResponse> =>{
const axiosClient = AxiosClient.createInstance();

try {
    const response = await axiosClient.get(`api/v1/getUser/${id}`);

    return {
       success: true,
       data: response.data
   }
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);

    return {
       success: false,
       data: isAxiosError(err) ? err.message: (err as string)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I asked this to my mentor and he said the path will not need an id params. Also in the controller, we are using req.body to get userId, which works. `const userData = await getSingleUser(req.body.userId)`.